# With jquery mobile - left right scroll

Tags: jquery-mobile, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am using Jquery mobile.
I am trying to make a carosol like the one in market app.
How ever mine is all web based.
I have seen the swipe at iscroll it is nice but hard to get working in the JQM.
I thought it would be easy:

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow-x: hidden; scroll-x: auto;">
<img src="1.jpg">   <img src="2.jpg">   <img src="3.jpg">
</div>
```

Was I ever wrong.
I know the subject has be dealt with but I didn't find a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Flexslider](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/). Works nice with Jquery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Another fresh slider script is: [SwipeJS](http://swipejs.com/)

I successfully implemented iscroll after a few try in a jQM project. Maybe you used duplicate id's or placed the functions in wrong place.

Comment: I've seen this suggested in several places, but the site doesn't seem to work. Is the project dead?

Answer (score 0):

code that looks for [data-scroll] will eventually be folded into the jqm page processing code when scrollview support is "official" instead of "experimental".
currentlly scroll-x: auto; is not supported in release of jqm 1.0.1.
you can use scrollview.js http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js